# Error: Application entry point file not found

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, angular-schematics

I used this link https://blog.angular.io/apps-that-work-natively-on-the-web-and-mobile-9b26852495e7 to create a new shared application and it showed site on browser correctly. But when I built apk and installed in mobile, its showing error "Application entry point file not found"

Commands I followed:

ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics --name=my-app --shared

cd my-app

tns build android

---> generated apk file which I tried to run on mobile but got error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `tns build android --bundle` command as code shared projects work only with `--bundle` option.